# How to summarize segmented roadway data in Python using Pandas similar to a GIS dissolve operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gis

I have segmented roadway data that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

input_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ROUTE': ['US9', 'US9', 'US9', 'US9', 'US9'],
    'BMP':   [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
    'EMP':   [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
    'VALUE': [19, 19, 232, 232, 19]
})

>>> print(input_df)
BMP  EMP ROUTE  VALUE
0.0  0.1   US9     19
0.1  0.2   US9     19
0.2  0.3   US9    232
0.3  0.4   US9    232
0.4  0.5   US9     19
```

The `BMP` column represents the begin milepoint of this attribute along a linear referenced GIS representation of the road. The `EMP` is the associated end mileage. When the VALUE column is equal, I would like to combine adjacent segments.

There is a tool that does this operation in `ArcGIS` called [Dissolve Route Events](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/dissolve-route-events.htm). I would like to use Pandas to complete this task. Here's the desired output:

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ROUTE': ['US9', 'US9', 'US9'],
    'BMP':   [0.0, 0.2, 0.4],
    'EMP':   [0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
    'VALUE': [19, 232, 19]
})

>>> print(output_df)
BMP  EMP ROUTE  VALUE
0.0  0.2   US9     19
0.2  0.4   US9    232
0.4  0.5   US9     19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
input_df['trip'] = (input_df.VALUE.diff() != 0).cumsum()
output_df = input_df.groupby(['ROUTE','trip','VALUE']).agg({'BMP':'first','EMP':'last'})
output_df.reset_index()
#
    ROUTE   trip    VALUE   BMP EMP
0   US9 1   19  0.0 0.2
1   US9 2   232 0.2 0.4
2   US9 3   19  0.4 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This solution also works with categorical data. Just convert the value column to a pandas category type using `input_df['VALUE'].astype('category')`. Then use `input_df.VALUE.cat.codes.diff() != 0`